# Como adiciono atributos na img com a função the_post_thumbnail do WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso adicionar um `width="100%"` e o `class="img-responsive"`.

Como faço para adicionar na img se eu chamo ela na index desta maneira?

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: Tente desta forma <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 4):

Faz assim:

```
<?php
  $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
  $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
  echo "<img src='".$thumb_url[0]."' width='100%' class='img-responsive' />";
?>
```

`get_post_thumbnail_id` pega o id da thumb.

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` pega a url da imagem, passando o id da thumb como parâmetro.

Comment: Muito bom, me ajudou também!

Comment: Opa deu certo, valeu cara! e vai ajudar em projetos futuros!